Disk and open report errors
Both Disk and link click report disc error:

Any suggestions of a fix?

You've provided few specifics (no real clue as to what OS/release you're using, what you're trying to do etc), but your first unmounting error would imply to me you're trying to umount a file-system that currently is in-use, either you have a process (terminal or something that has something open on it; maybe has the $PWD set to it; ie. you've cd or changed directory to a location on the drive), OR you've just written loads of data to the drive which currently exists in cache & write hasn't completed, where waiting is your answer, OR .... etc.  Consider what you were doing.

OS is Ubuntu, problem surfaced yesterday without reason that I am aware of. Disks are Toshiba both 1tB, attached USB drives, plenty of room left on both.

Using Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS not subscribed to Pro
